# Multiple Collapsible divs bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion, bootstrap-modal, collapsable, bootstrap-carousel

I am creating a gallery with albums in Bootstrap 3.3.6.  The albums consist of an album cover which reveals or hides the album pics inside a collapsible `<div>`.  Collapsible `<div>` is also accordion style.

I have 2 layouts for mobile and desktop using media queries and Bootstrap's .hidden-* class.  Also, when you click on one of the pics within the album it opens a carousel to scroll through the images.

The code works perfectly, but I would like the collapsible `<div>` to remain open though the layout changes as the page resizes.  Right now it opens on click and then when you resize the screen down past the break point it closes as the layout changes with the breakpoint.

I realize this is a bit unnecessary because basically no one is going to resize their browser this way on a desktop, but I still want to know how to do it.  Can't figure it out.

here is a sample of the code, you can see how the layout changes from desktop to mobile.

See it in action here www.leubasketball.com/gallery

```
 <div class="panel-group text-center" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 hidden-xs">
<!--Desktop Gallery------------------------------>

<!--Album Covers--------------------------------->
    <!--Skillcase 2016 Album Cover----------------------->
        <div class="col-sm-3 panel-heading" role="tab" id="skillcase2016">
              <div class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSkillcase2016" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseSkillcase2016">
                  <h4 style="color:#ffffff">Skillcase 2016</h4>
                    <img src="img/completeplayerimage.jpg" class="albumCover img-responsive">
                </a>
              </div>
        </div>
    <!--St Goerge 2016 Album Cover----------------------->
       <div class="col-sm-3 panel-heading" role="tab" id="stgeorge2016">
          <div class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseStgeorge2016" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseStgeorge2016">
              <h4 style="color:#ffffff">St. George 2016</h4>
                <img src="img/completeplayerimage.jpg" class="albumCover img-responsive">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>

<!--Albums-------------------------------------------->           
    <!--Skillcase 2016 Album--------------------------->         
        <div id="collapseSkillcase2016" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="skillcase2016">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <!--Thumbnails-------->
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 hidden-xs">
         <!--Carousel Modal here-------------------------------------->
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <!--Skillcase 2016 Album--------------------------->         
        <div id="collapseStgeorge2016" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="stgeorge2016">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <!--Thumbnails-------->
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 hidden-xs">
         <!--Carousel Modal here-------------------------------------->
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>

<!--Mobile Gallery---------------------------------------->

    <!--Mobile Album Covers-------------------------------->            
        <!--Skillcase 2016 Album Cover---------------------->
       <div class="col-xs-6 visible-xs panel-heading" role="tab" id="skillcase2016M">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSkillcase2016M" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSkillcase2016M, collapseSkillcase2016">
                  <h4 style="color:#ffffff">Skillcase 2016</h4>
                    <img src="img/completeplayerimage.jpg" class="albumCover img-responsive">
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <!--St. George 2016 Album Cover------------------->       
       <div class="col-xs-6 visible-xs panel-heading" role="tab" id="stgeorge2016M">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseStgeorge2016M" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseStgeorge2016M">
                  <h4 style="color:#ffffff">St. George 2016</h4>
                    <img src="img/completeplayerimage.jpg" class="albumCover img-responsive">
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
<!--Mobile Albums--------------------------------------->
        <!--Skillcase 2016 Album---------------------------->
        <div id="collapseSkillcase2016M" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="skillcase2016M">
          <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
          <!--Carousel Modal here------------------------->
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--St George 2016 Album---------------------------->
        <div id="collapseStgeorge2016M" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="stgeorge2016M">
          <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
          <!--Carousel Modal here------------------------->
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>



    </div>
</div>
```